# yii2 disable inbuilt authentication

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-user

I have written my own `Users` model which extends `ActiveRecord` and implements `IdentityInterface` and also defined tablename. and implemented all methods.

Users.php

```
public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'users';
    }
// other methods are also present like rules() , getId() etc.
```

UserController.php

```
public function actionLogin()
    {
        $this->layout = 'blank';

        if (!Yii::$app->myuser->isGuest) {
            return 'hello';
        }


        $model = new UserLoginForm();
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->login()) {
            return $this->redirect(['user/view',
                'id' => $model->getUser()->id,
            ]);
        } else {
            $model->password = '';

            return $this->render('login', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }
    }
```

UserLoginForm.php

```
<?php

namespace backend\models;

use Yii;
use yii\base\Model;

class UserLoginForm extends Model
{

    public $username;
    public $password;
    public $rememberMe = true;

    private $_user;


    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            // username and password are both required
            [['username', 'password'], 'required'],
            // rememberMe must be a boolean value
            ['rememberMe', 'boolean'],
            // password is validated by validatePassword()
            ['password', 'validatePassword'],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Validates the password.
     * This method serves as the inline validation for password.
     *
     * @param string $attribute the attribute currently being validated
     * @param array $params the additional name-value pairs given in the rule
     */
    public function validatePassword($attribute, $params)
    {
        if (!$this->hasErrors()) {
            $user = $this->getUser();
            if (!$user || !$user->validatePassword($this->password)) {
                $this->addError($attribute, 'Incorrect username or password.');
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Logs in a user using the provided username and password.
     *
     * @return bool whether the user is logged in successfully
     */
    public function login()
    {
        if ($this->validate()) {
            return Yii::$app->myuser->login($this->getUser());
        }

        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Finds user by [[username]]
     *
     * @return Users|null
     */
    public function getUser()
    {
        if ($this->_user === null) {
            $this->_user = Users::findByUsername($this->username);
        }

        return $this->_user;
    }
}
```

And in backend/config/main.php

```
'myuser' => [
            'class' => 'yii\web\User',
            'identityClass' => 'backend\models\Users',
            'enableAutoLogin' => true,
            'identityCookie' => ['name' => '_identity-backend_user', 'httpOnly' => true],
        ],
```

But after successful login, i get following error

```
The table does not exist: {{%user}}
```

I found that it is calling common/models/User.php class which by default present in advanced template. But why is it calling this class ? I want to use my own Users.php model. Please somone help me to fix this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class used for authentication is determined by the [user](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-web-user) application component, according to the [authentication section](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/security-authentication) of the Yii2 guide:

> The user application component manages the user authentication status. It requires you to specify an identity class which contains the actual authentication logic. In the following application configuration, the identity class for user is configured to be app\models\User whose implementation is explained in the next subsection:

When you configure a new `myuser` component, the framework still uses the `user` component as it is configured by default, update your code, so it overwrites the `user` component, instead of creating a new `myuser` one.

```php
'user' => [
    // Points to your custom class
    'identityClass' => 'backend\models\Users',
    'enableAutoLogin' => true,
    'identityCookie' => ['name' => '_identity-backend', 'httpOnly' => true],
],
```

Comment: what should i write in user component? "point to your custom class" means what?

Comment: Points to your custom class is just a comment, in your question it looks like the class you want to use is `backend\models\Users`, so I used that one. Update the `user` component on the components section of `backend/config/main` so its `identityClass` points to your class.

Comment: I just saw that your `Users` class is under the `backend\models` namespace, I updated the answer.